# How to quote a quote with added words

Tags: writing, quotations

The original text in the source is as follows:

> "there is a psychological need for... [a] sense-making narrative" (Rosen 2008: xix).

I would like to quote this line in a paper I'm writing. Do I need to do anything to indicate that the author of my source (*not* Rosen and not me) added the word [a], or can I leave it as is? Unfortunately, I'm using a Google Preview version of my source and don't have access to the full Rosen citation, let alone the Rosen source.

Comment: A Google Search indicates that the quotation comes from the introduction to Elizabeth Rosen, [_Apocalyptic Transformation: Apocalypse and the Postmodern Imagination_](https://books.google.com/books?id=mU4eAAAAQBAJ&pg=PR19&dq=%22psychological+need+for%22+%22sense-making+narrative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmp5WY3pnMAhUL3WMKHVmzAfkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22psychological%20need%20for%22%20%22sense-making%20narrative%22&f=false) (2008), page xix. This doesn't answer your question of how to quote a quotation that already has interpolated (bracketed] additions, but it may solve your immediate problem.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Quotations and Square Brackets](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189795/quotations-and-square-brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The citation rules will depend on the style required by the school (for example, MLA, Harvard, APA, Chicago, etc.). What you are doing is called [secondary referencing](https://www.google.com/search?q=secondary%20refererence&oq=secondary%20refererence&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6038j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=secondary%20reference) and you can add to that search the type of citation style your school requires to find out the specifics for how to do it in your paper.

**As an example, if you were using the Harvard citation style, I believe you could write it like this:**

Rosen (2008), cited by Magid in Gallardo and Russell (2014), states "there is a psychological need for... [a] sense-making narrative".

**Then in your References list, you write it this way:**

Magid, A. (2014) 'Intimations of Hope within Apocalyptic and Post-Apocalyptic Context' in Gallardo, P. and Russell, E. (eds) *Yesterday's Tomorrows: On Utopia and Dystopia,* Cambridge, Cambridge Scholars Publishing, pp. 45-58.

**Or you could sidestep the issue:**

Have you considered side-stepping the issue by using [Google Preview to get the full Rosen quote](https://books.google.com/books?id=4R0DaBBxIcQC&lpg=PR19&vq=sense-making%20narrative&pg=PA1#v=snippet&q=sense-making%20narrative&f=false), and then citing that? Here's the full quote directly from Rosen:

"If we want to understand why the creative imagination seems to have gravitated toward the traditional paradigm at the end of the twentieth century, we might argue that as the psychological need for this sense-making narrative has become somehow more acute, the corresponding desire for what Richard Cizik calls 'moral certitudes in a world without any certainties' has grown" (Rosen, 2008, p. xix).